# Please, help me to simplify this expression

Tags: lua, trigonometry

This is a line of trigonomical code I have. I would like to know if there is a way to simplify it to make it faster. Thanks

```
abs((a%(2*math.pi)-b%(2*math.pi))%(2*math.pi)-math.pi)
```

Comment: im not sure they are always things that go hand in hand - simplification and performance improvements!  Which one would you like to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calculating the subexpression `((a % 2pi) - (b % 2pi)) % 2pi)`. Due to the properties of modulo, `(a%c - b%c) % c == (a-b) % c`, so therefore you can omit the inner modulos. The full expression will become:

```
abs((a-b) % (2*math.pi) - math.pi)
```

Comment: Ok, it works very Well.I'm sure it does computer a little faster than the first version. Thanks Interjay.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely store the result of `2*math.pi` in a local variable. That would save you a few table lookups (global for `math` and then `math` for `pi`).

If you're using it in a loop, declare the local variable before the loop and also make `abs` a local.

Comment: FYI, there are very good reasons to GENERALLY use `2*math.pi` ;) See http://tauday.com/